# Not able to edit in entity framework with asp.net/c#

Tags: c#, entity-framework

```
 public ReturnMessage EditCategories(Category objCategory)
    {


        ReturnMessage objReturnMessage = new ReturnMessage();
        try
        {
            Category objCategoryNew = db.Categories.Where(x => x.CategoryId == objCategory.CategoryId).FirstOrDefault();
            if (objCategoryNew != null)
            {
                objCategoryNew = objCategory;
                db.SaveChanges();
                objReturnMessage.isSuccessfull = true;
                objReturnMessage.responseMessage = "Successfully updated.";
            }
            else
            {
                objReturnMessage.isSuccessfull = false;
                objReturnMessage.responseMessage = "Category not present.";
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            objReturnMessage.isSuccessfull = false;
            objReturnMessage.responseMessage = ex.Message;
        }
        return objReturnMessage;

    }
```

Everything goes fine there are no exceptions still the data isn't getting updated. I don't know what's the issue. Please help?

Comment: No it isn't null contains the old data. Its coming inside the if loop itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line:

```
objCategoryNew = objCategory;
```

will not work out since you change the reference `objCategoryNew` to `objCategory`, not the object itself, what you have to do is to assign each property of `objCategory` to `objCategoryNew`, something like:

```
objCategoryNew.Pro1 = objCategory.Pro1;
objCategoryNew.Pro2 = objCategory.Pro2;
....
```